# Is OTA_VehResLLSRQ car sell request?

Tags: sabre

I have a ProgramId and membershipID for car loyalty program. I'm sending it in the Book Car Reservation (OTA_VehResLLSRQ) in VehResRQCore ->RateQualifier -> CustLoyalty. However in Sabre side we see it as FT-YYABC123, but it should be ID-YYABC123. How to do it?